# ImageIcon padding and/or alignment in a JButton

Tags: java, swing

*edited so it might be helpful to others:

I was struggling with why an ImageIcon was being padded in a JPanel, but not in a JToolBar even though they were added in the same way, using the same file (see the folder icon):

[image]

Cutting down the code to an sscce has shown that VGR's answer below is right - it's has to be how each component deals with JButtons, rather than the layout.

This code should run, but you'll have to have "images/open.png" in the source folder.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JToolBar;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

class CandidatePanel extends JPanel{

private JPanel panel = new JPanel();
private JToolBar tb = new JToolBar();
private JButton tbButton = new JButton();
private JButton cvButton = new JButton();

public static void main(String[] args){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.add(new CandidatePanel());
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true); 
}

public CandidatePanel(){
    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    tbButton.setIcon(new PanelHelper().createIcon("images/open.png", ""));
    tb.add(tbButton);

    cvButton.setIcon(new PanelHelper().createIcon("images/open.png", ""));
    cvButton.setFocusPainted(false);
    cvButton.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    cvButton.setBorderPainted(true);

    addComponents();
    add(tb);
    add(panel);
}

private void addComponents(){
    panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    int row =0;

    //new row
    JPanel cvButtonPanel = (JPanel)PanelHelper.addTestBorder(new JPanel(),Color.BLUE);

    cvButtonPanel.add(cvButton);
    cvButtonPanel.add(PanelHelper.addTestBorder(new JPanel(), Color.RED));

    panel.add(tb, new GBC(1,row));
    panel.add(cvButtonPanel, new GBC(1,++row));
} 
}

class PanelHelper{

public static JComponent addTestBorder(JComponent comp, Color color){
    Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(color);
    comp.setBorder(border);
    return comp;
}

public ImageIcon createIcon(String path, String btnName){
    URL url = getClass().getResource(path);
    if(url == null)
        System.err.println("\nThe "+btnName+" Icon Path Cannot Be Found: "+path);
    return new ImageIcon(url);
}
}
```

it was just as simple as setting the button margin, as mentioned in the comments below.

`button.setMargin(new Insets(0,0,0,0))`

Comment: There's a lot of code here, including quite a bit that is just a screenshot of code and couldn't be copy/pasted by someone trying to help.  Could you produce a separate program with just the two icons/buttons that reproduces the problem?  Unless this is a general problem with JButtons I don't think anyone could help given your question as it is now.

Comment: yeah sorry, I'll try and add an SSCCE now. I'm just struggling with the fact that it's part of a much bigger program, which probably makes it hard to replicate. I added the picture of the code in order to highlight the relevant JButton. Probably not the best idea. Anyway, I'll see what I can come up with.

Comment: It's cool.  If it was a general problem, you could have gotten a quick answer.  An actual MCVE takes a bit of time.

Comment: The library is just closing, but I think I've managed to recreate the problem. Will post the code when I get back home. Think I'll edit the original post so that it's more helpful to others. Thanks!

Comment: It is normal for a JButton to have a smaller margin when it is in a JToolBar.  That is by design.  You can override it by changing the button’s margin using its inherited [setMargin](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setMargin-java.awt.Insets-) method.

Comment: thanks VGR - I'm going to try that now

Comment: yeah, that worked, thanks, question updated.

Comment: You're allowed to [answer your own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/17463).